# DataGridView put text in ColumnHeader of RowHeader

Tags: c#, datagridview, columnheader, rowheader

Is it possible to add text into ColumnHeader of the RowHeader. I put autoincrement into Rowheaders of my DataGridView and I would like to put "No." above that.

Something like:

```
//Autoincrement RowHeaders
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in myDGV.Rows)
{
    row.HeaderCell.Value = String.Format("{0}", row.Index + 1);
}

No. | myColumn 1 | myColumn 2

1   | myText     | myText
2   | myText     | myText

//the "No." column are actually RowHeaders
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So basically you need to display "No." in top left corner?

That area is called `TopLeftHeaderCell`. It is just like the other `DataGridViewCell`, you can set its `Value` property to achieve the task.

```
dataGridView.TopLeftHeaderCell.Value = "No.";
```